# Unknown characters while reading PDF file from Azure Blobl Storage

Tags: azure, pdf, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I want to read PDF from azure blob storage and convert it into Base64 format. Following is the code that works fine with `.txt` file format but for `.pdf` file, it gives unknown characters which I understood is because of binary data format of PDF. How can I fix this code to get valid pdf and encode it with Base64.

```
            BlobAsyncClient blobAsyncClient = containerClient.getBlobAsyncClient("abc/abc.pdf");
            ByteArrayOutputStream downloaded= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            return blobAsyncClient.downloadStream().doOnNext(piece -> {
                try {
                    downloaded.write(piece.array());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
                }
             }).doOnComplete(() -> {
                log.info("File downloading completed...");
                log.info(String.valueOf(downloaded)); // getting garbage value even before encoiding the bytes
            })
                .then(
Mono.defer(()->Mono.just(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(downloaded.toByteArray()))));
```

Value populated in `downloaded` is:

```
%����
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en) /StructTreeRoot 14 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 28 0 R/ViewerPreferences 29 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 12 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS10 10 0 R/GS11 11 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 257>>
stream
x��PMK�0���+4}��M%�ۏEqҊ'���Z���A���#�ޣ�>LTU龾l��aiu���~#m��^���|[r�`�����MZm�Ҏ������䭁u�L./O�����S��?۝V��eL\�M�%�,e.���2N�9,�7Q�@&���D �]|��J�V��h�[��Μ _|�^Ȯh}���}Mtj)���E�
'$���n�1H6s����\    �������tzb
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/BaseFont/BCDEEE+Calibri/Encoding/Identity-H/DescendantFonts 6 0 R/ToUnicode 24 0 R>>
endobj
```

The actual content of this pdf file is just:

```
Download
Test 1
```

Comment: `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(downloaded.toByteArray()))` <-- You shouldn't need to do any of this.

Comment: Edited the question. Even before encoding, values look unknown.

Comment: PDF is a binary file format - you're not meant to treat it like a `.txt` file nor be able to "read it" by trying to treat it like text.

Comment: @Akanksha_p I got the Base64 data of the pdf file in the [terminal](https://i.imgur.com/gypvwWp.png) as output and the blob pdf file was downloaded in the project directory as [this](https://i.imgur.com/3nm2Vwt.png). This is the pdf blob [data](https://i.imgur.com/yuGM0Ib.png).

Comment: @DasariKamali - does that means whatever data I'm getting before encoding is correct to re-create the pdf file in same format?

Comment: @Dai - can you suggest an approach where I can get the file content and encode it such that if someone else tries to decode the content, they'll be able to reconstruct exact same pdf?

Comment: Because you're overusing the word "encoding" I think you misunderstand the problem here...